# Ruby execute methods in a thread

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I have a ruby script for a twitch bot. It's main methods are run() to start it, and quit() to close the bot. Following posts online it seems like I can make a thread by doing:

```
TWITCH_BOT = Thread.new{ BOT = TwitchBot.new }
```

To which I then need to join it to keep it alive?

```
TWITCH_BOT.join()
```

How do I go about executing the run() command from the TwitchBot within the thread, rather than the thread trying to perform run()?

Comment: We don't know what Twitch bot you're using or any of the features that exist for it. Perhaps you can provide a link to the repository for the specific twitch bot you're running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though there could be a whole dissertation written about safe asynchronous code, if it's for a simple bot, why not write the code like this?

```
class TwitchBot
...
  def run(&code_block)
    @thread = Thread.start &code_block
  end
  ...
  def quit
    @thread.exit unless @thread.nil?
  end
  ...
end
```

EDIT: Or are you using a twitch bot that someone else wrote? In which case, maybe write a wrapper that does something like the above.

Comment: This should be perfect, it is indeed a simple bot that just reads the messages and stores them in an array.